# c# System.OutOfMemoryException in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, roslyn, vsix

I am using VS 2017. I am getting "OutOfMemory in mscorlib.dll" exception in my vsix project. I am using Roslyn in this project, below is my method to find Field Declaration and references.

```
public static async Task FindFieldDeclarationAndReferencesAsync(string solutionPath, List<Violation> violations) 
{           
    var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
    var solution = await msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);***//The solution I am passing to this workspace is 1 GB***
    var documents = solution.Projects.SelectMany(x => x.Documents).ToList();

    foreach (var violation in violations)//violations.Count is approximately 10
    {
        var classFile = documents.Where(x => x.FilePath == violation.FilePath).FirstOrDefault();
        var model = await classFile.GetSemanticModelAsync();
        var root = await classFile.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
        var classDeclarationNode = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Where(x => x.Identifier.Text == violation.ClassName).FirstOrDefault();

        var fieldDeclarationNodeList = classDeclarationNode.DescendantNodes().OfType<FieldDeclarationSyntax>().Where(m => m.Modifiers.ToString().Contains("public const")).SelectMany(x => x.Declaration.Variables.Where(y => y.Identifier.Text == violation.FieldName)).FirstOrDefault();

        ISymbol fieldSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(fieldDeclarationNodeList);
        var fieldReferences = await SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(fieldSymbol, solution);
        violation.FieldDeclaration = fieldDeclarationNodeList;
        violation.Replacement = Helpers.GetIdentifierReplacement(violation.FieldName);
        violation.References = fieldReferences.SelectMany(item => item.Locations).ToList();
    }               
}
```

Am I getting this exception as the solution size is 1 GB which is passed to Roslyn while creating workspace?

**Exception Details:**

```
System.OutOfMemoryException
  HResult=0x8007000E
  Message=Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Capture(StackCrawlMark& stackMark, CaptureOptions options) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 1281
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.FastCapture() in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 1190
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.GetCompletionAction(Task taskForTracing, MoveNextRunner& runnerToInitialize) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\runtime\compilerservices\AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:line 916
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted[TAwaiter,TStateMachine](TAwaiter& awaiter, TStateMachine& stateMachine) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\runtime\compilerservices\AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:line 543
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(Object state) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\runtime\compilerservices\AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:line 1034
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\threadpool.cs:line 1273
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 954
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 901
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\threadpool.cs:line 1250
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\threadpool.cs:line 819
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\threadpool.cs:line 1161
```

I checked the Handles in TaskManager for my process and below are the values.

[image: TaskManager-handles]

I want to get out of this exception. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: What's the bit of your windows 64 or 32?

Comment: Go to Task Manager and save a dump of the VS process. Then try to open that dump in VS. Maybe you can find out which objects are being created and not released.

Comment: Hi Abdul, its windows 64.

Comment: Hi Paulo, I got the dump and opened in VS but not sure where to find the objects created and not released. Now I installed WinDbg and trying bbut getting the following error .loadby sos clr
The call to LoadLibrary(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos) failed, Win32 error 0n193
    "%1 is not a valid Win32 application."

Comment: How should I analyse my dump file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the object which was taking more memory using *Visual studio "Diagnostic Tools" window*. Taken memory screenshot at the start and end of the code and compared both and fixed the issue.

`violation.FieldDeclaration` and `violation.References` took so much memory when the `violations` object count is huge.
so setting those `properties to null` in the `finally` block at the end of each iteration has fixed the issue for me.